# How can I insert a newline into a SQL/Rails string record?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, newline

I have a string record `@user.location` that I'm printing into an ERB file, and I'd like it to read:

```
"first line
second line"
```

So far I've tried:

```
@user.location = "first line" + "\n" + "second line"
@user.location = "first line" + '\n' + "second line"
@user.location = "first line" + "<br />" + "second line"
@user.location = "first line" + '<br />' + "second line"
@user.location = "first line
    second line"
```

But they all end up printing the literal characters instead of a newline. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: where do you want to output it? it works just fine with `puts "first line" + "\n" + "second line"`

Comment: @railsr Is there a way I can output the newline in erb just by writing `<%=@user.location%>`
?

Answer (score 1):

Your newlines (`\n`) don't mean anything in ERB (or, more specifically, HTML).

That's why rails has this nice little helper, [`simple_format`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format):

```
<%= simple_format(@user.location) %>
```

It treats `\n` characters as `<br/>` tags, among other things.